# How can I send a Word document as an attachment to a specific recipient?

Tags: email, ms-word, word-2010

I've created a form in Word 2010, and I added a button to send the form.
What i want is that when the button is clicked, the form is attached to an email message, and a specific email address is automaticlly entered in the 'To' field of the message.
I managed to get the button to open an email message and add the form as an attachment, but I can't get it to enter my email address.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are generating the email message. For example, see below for one method.

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

```
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next

    With OutMail
        .To = "test@test.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Subject goes here"
        .Body = "Text of body goes here."
        .Attachments.Add (\file\to\attach.txt)
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```